# Android Wear DotspageIndicator changing the color of selected dot

Tags: wear-os

I like to change the color of selected dot in wear's Dotspageindicator. I tried using setColor() and setSelectedColor() but the color is not changing still default behavior.

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution the problem is setting color they are redrawing the view without updating the paint.

To update the paint set the radius of the dot. It will redraw the view after updating the paint.