# How change layout of DotsPageIndicator in android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to change default size and color of DotsPageIndicator in android wear , I tried to change color by `setDotColor` and `setDotColorSelected` but noyhing change , is there another way to change color and size? , is there third party library?.
my code:

```
final GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new LoggedinAdapter(this));

DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
dotsPageIndicator.setDotColor(R.color.red);
dotsPageIndicator.setDotColorSelected(R.color.black);
dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the color the following worked for me:

```
mDotsPageIndicator.setDotRadius((int) (mDotsPageIndicator.getDotRadius()));
```

all thanks to this post:

> To update the paint set the radius of the dot. It will redraw the view after updating the paint.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192263/4072710